# Schema migrations in PonyORM

Tags: ponyorm

if one modifies a schema created with [the online editor](https://editor.ponyorm.com/), does PonyORM perform the required `ALTER TABLE` statements to upgrade the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, PonyORM online editor doesn't perform migrations when schema is modified. You need to upgrade schema manually.

You can try to use migration tool from [orm-migrations](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/tree/orm-migrations/pony/migrate) branch. It is not officially released yet. You can copy model definitions from online editor, save them in some `models.py` file in you project, and use migration tool to create migration. For simple migrations, like, adding attribute or relationship, it should work.

Comment: It looks like that branch stalled now? Last commit at Jul 30, 2018 and Pony stable version still 0.7.10.